# I want to deform the mesh by script

Tags: python, scripting, blender, mesh

The log could not be seen in the sculpt mode deformed.
For that reason, it is partially deformed by the "sphere" of proportional editing.

```
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(4.95114, 0, 0), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='ENABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SPHERE', proportional_size=15.8631, release_confirm=True, use_accurate=False)
```

When I run this script, the selected part does not swell to a sphere, but the whole original model moves. 
I think it is happening because there is no part to specify the center point in the script.
But I couldn't specify the center or other solutions.

What is the way to do proportional editing by script?Let me know if there are other ways you can do it in a script as well.

Comment: If you want help scripting blender, you will find better support at [blender.stackexchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com).

Comment: OK,I'll ask question there.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [`bpy.ops.transform.translate`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.transform.html#bpy.ops.transform.translate) is used in object and edit mode, the object needs to be in edit mode for the selected vertices to be moved.

In sculpt mode, the operator used would be [`bpy.ops.sculpt.brush_stroke`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.sculpt.html#bpy.ops.sculpt.brush_stroke). Using that in a script will involve setting up an [`OperatorStrokeElement`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.OperatorStrokeElement.html) which would include mouse position...

If you want to deform a mesh by script, you should look into using [bmesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Is it possible to perform proportional editing by specifying Median in script?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "DRAW" or "CLOTH" brush in sculpt mode like so:

```
def sculpt(coordinates, strength=0.5):
    bpy.ops.paint.brush_select(sculpt_tool="DRAW", toggle=False)
    bpy.data.brushes["SculptDraw"].strength = strength
    strokes = []
    for i, coordinate in enumerate(coordinates):
        stroke = {
            "name": "stroke",
            "mouse": (0,0),
            "pen_flip" : False,
            "is_start": True if i==0 else False,
            "location": coordinate,
            "size": 50,
            "pressure": 1,
            "time": float(i)
        }
        strokes.append(stroke)
    bpy.ops.sculpt.brush_stroke(context_override(), stroke=strokes)
    print("Finished sculpting")
```

`sculpt([(0,0,1),(0,0,0.5),(0,0,1)])`

Taken from [here](https://github.com/christian-vorhemus/procedural-3d-image-generation/blob/master/blenderBackgroundTask.py#L54).